# sufficient, minimal, complete

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics

Are all complete statistics functions of each other?

For example if I have T and S complete statistics

Can you always write T in terms of S and S in terms of T?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Normal $\mathcal N(\mu,1)$ sample, $x_1,\ldots,x_{2n}$. Then both $\bar X_{1:n}$ and $\bar X_{(n+1):2n}$ are complete, insufficient, and not a function of one another.